# How can I use git hash as build version or CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, xcode, git, app-store-connect

I have been use the short git revision hash as the build version for my project. The intention is to make it easy to cross reference between releases and git commits. However, when I am trying to upload a build to iTunes Connect, I get an error indicating the build version cannot have letters.

```
"Invalid value '1.3.7 (1bc4e83)' for bundle_version...
```

Looking around the web, I could not find a viable solution. A common way I have seen is to just to use a number and increment it for every build. This does not fulfil my need of cross referencing. Is there way to do that? What is the common practise?

Answer (score 1):

You can decimalise the commit SHA (which is just a hexadecimal number). So for example `1bc4e83` would become `29118083`. You still need each build number to be larger than the last though so you can prepend the SHA with the number of commits on the branch, e.g. `git rev-list HEAD --count`. The end result is a build number like `302.29118083`.

If you're using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/), that can be implemented as:

```
sha_hex = last_git_commit[:abbreviated_commit_hash]
build_number = "#{number_of_commits}.#{sha_hex.to_i(16)}"
increment_build_number(build_number: build_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120519210552/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#/web/20120516081816/http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html):

> `CFBundleVersion` specifies the build version number of the bundle, which identifies an iteration (released or unreleased) of the bundle. **This is a monotonically increased string, comprised of one or more period-separated integers.**

So, you cannot use your git hash as a `CFBundleVersion` because it is not a monotonically increased string with periods as separators.

For an alternative solution, you can include the build number in your commit's message.